# JavaScript plus unary operator returns NaN

Tags: javascript, browser

When trying to convert a string to number in a browser console:

```
let a="3,437,286"
+a
```

returns `NaN`. Do you see what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string isn't a proper number. Maybe if the string always has numbers with commas, you can remove the commas and try to check it:

```js
let a = "3,437,286";
console.log(+a);                    // NaN
console.log(+a.replace(/,/g, ""));  // 3437286
```

Comment: `if the string always has numbers with commas` even if it doesn't have a comma, your code is correct ...